# Visual Studio 2022 Web publish to IIS asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, publish, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to publish my asp.net core 3.1 application to IIS running on a remote computer using Visual Studio 2022 and I don't know what to put in the inputs for the "Publish" dialog. I already have the site working (used a publish to file and then copied over to IIS server with dot.net core runtime installed for site).

[image: Publish Dialog]

When I click on "Validate Connection" I get an error that says: Failed to connect to the remote computer with "#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC". I've verified that the Web Management Service is running on the server. How do I check to see if the firewall is blocking it?

Plus, I don't really even know if I have the right entries in the input fields on the dialog box.

Anyone know of a good tutorial that goes through ALL the steps (and not just "verify that such-and-such is configured - I don't know how to do that).

TIA,
Owen

Comment: I'm pretty sure to deploy direct like that you need Web Platform Installer with Web Deploy installed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later